# PHP code to check country from IP

Tags: php

I understand how to code this all. My question is: say I got a dump of the IP address ranges for countries, would it be changed at some sooner point of time? and how often?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the ability to install PECL extensions?

Comment: I can try installing it on XAMPP. I am running Apache and PHP on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a database such as IP2Location to resolve the country, then it won't change. It may change if you're using it for higher resolution geolocation, such as "resolve IP to postcode".

IP2Location releases regular updates to fine tune the higher resolution results for IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

No it does't change for any reason. Because if it changes frequently it becomes a big concern and issue in tracking geographical based web traffic. Many of the systems would fail like WebAnaltics software, IP2Location Software.