# Retrieve the country code in PHP

Tags: php

I'm a little lost with that.

How can I retrieve the ISO country code of the visitors at one php page?

Thanks advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP code to check country from IP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378318/php-code-to-check-country-from-ip)

Answer (score 2):

You can either do this by Geolocation of the IP or by inspecting the right headers.

Usually you want the latter, since it tells you which languages the browser/system uses. You will only want to use geolocation when you want to know the physical location.
The header is stored in `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`. It contains comma-separated entries, e.g.: `en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,nl;q=0.4` (my own)

The HTTP Accept Language parameters seperates it's languages by a comma, it's properties by a semicolon. The q-value is from 0 to 1, with 1 being the highest/most preferred. Here is some naive and untested code to parse it:

```
$langs = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
$preffered = "";
$prefvalue = 0;
foreach($langs as $lang){
    $info = explode(';', $lang);
    $val = (isset($lang[1])?$lang[1];1);
    if($prefvalue < $val){
        $preferred = $lang[0];
        $prefvalue = $val;
    }
}
```

Much simpler is it if you want to test if a specific language is accepted, e.g. Spanish (es):

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], "es") !== false){
    // Spanish is supported
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use this php script which uses an ip and prints out a country code

Example

`http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=4.2.2.2`

Gives `US`

Check out 
http://www.hostip.info/use.html
for more info.

Answer (score 1):

A library i use myself and can recommend, is [MaxMind GeoLite Country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry). To get the country code, you need only to copy 2 files to your server, the php code *geoip.inc* and the binary data *GeoIP.dat*.

Using the library is also very straightforward:

```
function ipToCountry()
{
  include_once('geoip/geoip.inc');

  $gi = geoip_open(__DIR__ . '/geoip/GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_STANDARD);
  $result = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  geoip_close($gi);

  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will use GeoIp and fall back to accept_lang

```
class Ip2Country
{
    function get( $target )
    {
        $country = false;
        if( function_exists( 'geoip_record_by_name' ) )
            $country = $this->getFromIp( $target );
        if( !$country && isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] ) )
            $country = $this->getFromLang( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] );
        return $country;
    }

    function getFromIp( $target )
    {
        $dat = @geoip_record_by_name( $target );
        return ( isset( $dat['country_code'] ) ) ? mb_strtolower( $dat['country_code'] ) : false;
    }

    function getFromLang( $str )
    {
        $info = array();
        $langs = explode( ',', $str );
        foreach( $langs as $lang )
        {
            $i = explode( ';', $lang );
            $j = array();
            if( !isset( $i[0] ) ) continue;
            $j['code'] = $i[0];
            if( strstr( $j['code'], '-' ) )
            {
                $parts = explode( '-', $j['code'] );
                $j['lang'] = $parts[0];
                $j['country'] = mb_strtolower( $parts[1] );
            }
            $info[] = $j;
        }
        return ( isset( $info[0]['country'] ) ) ? $info[0]['country'] : false;
    }
}

$x = new Ip2Country();
var_dump( $x->get( 'canada.ca' ) );
```